# Convert EDI 810 in CSV

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have created an project to convert the EDI 810 into CSV . I am getting the required output while testing locally but getting below error after deploying the solution in admin console.  I am using the EdiReceive pipeline.

*

> A message received by adapter "FILE" on receive location "Rl_EDI_RECEIVE" with URI "D:\810_INVOICE\RceiveEDI*.txt" is suspended. 
>    Error details: There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.DefaultPipelines.EdiReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "EDI disassembler" Receive Port: "RP_EDI_INVOICE" URI: "D:\810_INVOICE\RceiveEDI*.txt" Reason: No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data.
>    MessageId:  {D3641489-EE54-4720-B0E3-73192DB39A58}
>    InstanceID: {8363D39D-FCE0-4661-8C04-EECB4309A935}

Comment: Where is your UNH (Header record)?   Yes, you can test in Visual Studio without that, but to actually process you need that.   Also please add your sample file as text, rather than as an image.

Comment: I got the below error while testing with the data below & attached the scrrenshot which shows the schema deployed .                    Error encountered during parsing. The X12 transaction set with id '' contained in functional group with id '1425', in interchange with id '000020613', with sender id 'DITREX         ', receiver id 'WIRELE         ' is being suspended with following errors:
Error: 1 (Miscellaneous error)
 6: Finding the document specification by message type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/X12#X12_00401_810" failed. Verify the schema deployed properly.

Comment: Below is the input file ( not able to attached the txt file ) .ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*DITREX         *ZZ*WIRELE         *170812*1527*U*00401*000020613*0*T*>~
GS*IN*DITREX*WIRELE*20170812*1527*1425*X*004010~ST*810*269339~BIG*20170811*16604580*20170803*012150728529~REF*IA*WAAT~N1*ST*ADVOCA STORE ML*92*AL~N3*3705 HAMPTON ROAD*RECEIVING DEPARTMENT~N4*OCEAN*NY*11542~
N1*RI*CINGULAR ~N3*AT&T Mobility*675 West Peachtree St. NW~N4*ATLA*GA*37375~ITD*01*3****20171010*60*****NET-60~DTM*011*20170811~IT1*1*20*EA*670**SK*115440~TDS*9310000~TXI*GS*0~CTT*8~SE*23*269339~GE*1*1425~IEA*1*000020613~

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to add any new information.  If it is a new question post it as a new question, linking back to this one if it it gives context.

Comment: Have you checked if you do have that schema in your BizTalk Environment?  I believe that some of the EDI schema's are not in the Developer Edition.

Comment: Attached the screenshot that show the schema present in Biztalk location .

Comment: The screenshot show the namespace to be `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/Edi/X12/2016`  (note the BizTalk & 2016) with root X12_00401_810  So that does not match what you posted in your comments.

Comment: Is the schema deployed?  Did you disable the Fallback Settings?

Comment: Yes ( attached scheenshot ) .My goal is to convert the EDI 810 file into CSV . I was able to sucessfully test the map locally but not able to acheive the result after deployment . 
The receive location(RL) is passthrough of the EDI file ( ST to SE) .
The send port subscribing to the RL has the translation map .But please let me know the configuration that the send pipeline should have for sucessfull transformation .

Comment: The error in your question is with the Receive Location, and it is clearly indicating that either the configuration on there is wrong, or the schema is NOT deployed.

Comment: Thank you  Dijkgraaf , I was able to resolve this issue by creating corresponding parties & receive port (edi receive pipeline ) , send port ( flat file assemblier) .

Answer (score 1):

> No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data.

While you can test in VS with just the Transaction, ST..SE, you can only process full Interchanges, ISA..IEA, using the EDI Disassembler.

The sample in the screenshot in the Question will not process outside of Visual Studio.